# Selenium c#: Wait Until Element is Present Without Waiting the Time Given, Else Time Out

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element, wait

To explain further, I am currently working with selenium and c#. My problem is, my tool runs very fast without waiting the element to be ready.

`Thread.Sleep()` is not advisable for instance.

The given time to wait is 2 secs. the element will be present in 1 or more secs. after the `Thread.Sleep()` so the code line is not reliable.

Or the element is present but still waiting to finish `Thread.Sleep()` so it is time consuming.

What I want is, if the element is found then no need to wait on the given time, and if not found at the given time then time out.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly what [explicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and [expected conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) are for.

Uses example

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By locator));
```

This will wait **up** to 5 seconds for the element to be visible. If successful the element will be returned, if not it will throw `TimeoutException`.

**Update**

`ExpectedConditions` has moved and is now located in `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`

> 'ExpectedConditions' is obsolete: 'The ExpectedConditions
>   implementation in the .NET bindings is deprecated and will be removed
>   in a future release. This portion of the code has been migrated to the
>   DotNetSeleniumExtras repository on GitHub
>   (https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras)'

To avoid many changes in the existing code import the `ExpectedConditions` to a variable called `ExpectedConditions`. The rest of the code remains the same

```
using ExpectedConditions = SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions;
```

Comment: `ExpectedConditions` has deprecated now. Do you have any alternate solution for this?

Comment: Does it work on multi steps forms? I think the waiting starts when page is loaded, but until we reach the last step, timespan could've been passed already. right?

Comment: @Dohab the wait starts and ends in the `wait.Until` line.

Comment: I don't get it. Is it start from the last element action (click next to the next step), or from the page loading?

Comment: Oh I see, it depends on the condition.